# send email containing password when user account is created

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

Trying to send an email containing a password, when the user account is created. (with help from)    [How to send email from Asp.net Mvc-3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629647/how-to-send-email-from-asp-net-mvc-3)

```
public void SendEmail(string address, string subject, string message, string password)
    {
        string email = "emailAddress";
        //string password = "put-your-GMAIL-password-here";

        var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
        var msg = new MailMessage();
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
```

but smtpClient.Send(msg); returns the following error:

```
{System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at ACCS.StockControl.Controllers.UserLoginRecordController.SendEmail(String address, String subject, String message, String password)
   at ACCS.StockControl.Controllers.UserLoginRecordController.EditModalPOST(UserLoginRecordEditModalVM model)}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227532/gmail-530-5-5-1-authentication-required-learn-more-at)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't auth to Gmail smtp via MailMessage & smtpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104645/cant-auth-to-gmail-smtp-via-mailmessage-smtpclient)

Comment: Any Progress? Please make the changes in SSL and try again. Set Enable SSL to false

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 0):

It can be just with the wrong password and username.

Please try with *another fake password*, (e.g. "thisPasswordIsSurelyDontWork").
**If** your exception is same, then you have to **check** your creditentals, **Username, Password**

//or try

```
 smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
 loginInfo.To.Add("Emailaddress");
 loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("FromEmailaddress");
 loginInfo.Subject = "Subject";
 loginInfo.Body = "Body of the mail";
 loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
 smtp.Host = hostname;
 smtp.Port = 25; //in my case i am using 25
 smtp.EnableSsl = false; //enable ssl is set to false
 smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailId, sPassword);
 smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 smtp.Send(loginInfo);
 {
   Label.Visible = true;
   Label.Text = "A mail has been sent to you with the your username. Please check your inbox.";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by

```
 smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
```